# ant target for junit

Tags: java, ant, junit

i have Suite.java file as:

```
public class EshopServiceTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTestSuite(ImpactActionTypeTest.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(ProductServiceTest.class);
        return suite;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TestRunner.run(EshopServiceTestSuite .class);
    }

}
```

ImpactActionTypeTest.java file extends TestCase it is working fine. But ProductServiceTest.java

extends ESWTestCase which intern extends TestCase, this causes junit atrget to fail.

```
<error type="java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException">java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:94)
    at com.bgc.ecm.core.test.ElNinoAbstractTestCase.&lt;clinit&gt;(ElNinoAbstractTestCase.java:62)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
    at com.bgc.EshopServiceTestSuite.suite(EshopServiceTestSuite.java:41)
Caused by: sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:769)
    .....

</error>
  <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[log4j:WARN Caught Exception while in Loader.getResource. This may be innocuous.
sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index
```

EshopServiceTestSuite.java:41 is having code suite.addTestSuite(ProductServiceTest.class);
 Log4j is refered as:

```
- C:\build_libs\ESW\junit-3.8.1.jar
- C:\build_libs\ESW\log4j-1.2.15.jar
- C:\build_libs\ESW\log4j-1.2.8.jar
- C:\build_libs\ESW\mailapi.jar
```

why this exception is occuring?

Comment: Bad jar maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417239/questions-regarding-invalidjarindexexception

Comment: add code snippet here , jar version

Comment: Sounds like your Jar is corrupt.  Can you use `jar xvf ` to extract its contents?

Comment: Cross posted http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2225897&tstart=0

Comment: all jars are having properly included class files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class loader is looking for a class file in some jar and can't find it.

As your talking of `.java` files only - double check that all files have been compiled and added to the jar file.

Just saw that the exception occured in log4j - double-check that log4j.jar is on the class path while the test is executed.

Comment: - C:\build_libs\ESW\log4j-1.2.15.jar
 - C:\build_libs\ESW\log4j-1.2.8.jar          log4j is referred.

Comment: @akb you should only reference one version of log4j, this may be the cause for the error

Answer (score 0):

Check if your jar / one of your jars includes an index file (`META_INF/INDEX.LIST`). If yes, have a look at it, it may contain invalid index entries.

Here's an article about your exception: [Why does InvalidJarIndexException occur?](http://littletechsecrets.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/why-does-invalidjarindexexception-occur/)